# Including an image using <amp-img> without knowing the dimensions

Tags: amp-html

How do you publish an image in an AMP HTML article without knowing the image dimensions ahead of time?

Answer (score 3):

When the browser encounters an image tag without a size, it downloads the image and looks at the first few bytes to figure out the size. This is extremely inefficient because it has to happen over the user's high latency connection. The rest of my answer provides two alternatives for how to approach the problem:

**How to find out image dimensions on the server side (during publishing):**
Instead you can do the same thing on the server side during publishing with minimal overhead. Every CMS and server side language will have modules that allow finding image sizes. You can use something like ImageMagick (which has bindings for all programming languages), but you will likely find more specialized tools that do size determination only.

Examples modules for popular programming languages that can find image sizes:

- [node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size)
- [ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/imagesize/)
- [python](https://python-pillow.org/)
- [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

CMSes

- [WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

**What to do if you really cannot know the image dimensions:**
Independent of that, you can load images into AMP without knowing the size, by using `layout=fill` where the size of the image in the browser becomes independent of the actual size of the image. Another alternative is to use `layout=fixed` or `layout=responsive` and `img object-fit: contain`. This is useful if you always want the same dimensions for all your images.